# Prime numbers in Collatz sequences

Tags: prime-numbers, collatz-conjecture

This question/request is twofold. First, if this is a stupid question or if it has been addressed before, please say so (bluntness is optional), and I will crawl back into my cave...

My question: is there always at least one prime number in a Collatz sequence? If so, why? If anyone more knowledgable in number theory can provide me with (a link to) a proof, I'd appreciate it.

I have been playing around with this idea and if we disregard the prime number 2 the sequence will always be "attracted" to the prime number 5, which will then provide the ending sequence 16, 8, 4, 2, 1.

I then tried a number of starting values, ran them through the Collatz algorithm to see how many prime numbers there are before the sequence hits 5. There is always at least one prime number, most of the time there are more. Starting the sequence with 363 I came up with 9 primes before hitting on 5. With 364 there are 18. Some other starting values:

363 - 9 primes, 364 - 18, 365 - 18, 366 - 16, 367 - 9, 368 - 2, 369 - 2, 370 - 11

Even if you disregard this as a silly question, thanks for reading it anyway.

John

Comment: Powers of $2$ will only have $2$ as a prime on their way. $5\cdot 2^n$ will only have $5$ and $2$ on its way.

Comment: I suppose if the Collatz Conjecture proves to be true, that is each sequence will terminate in a 4-2-1 loop, then there will always be a prime number in any Collatz sequence.

Comment: I think that this could be an interesting question, if you were able to strip out the trivial cases. {1, 3, 5} times a power of 2 are obviously trivial, but are there others?

Comment: For example, 426 = 2*3*71 has no primes, but should it be excluded for some reason?

Comment: I suppose what we really want to know is if starting with any odd number, will its collatz sequence contain a prime.  I guess Charles answered that one, hah.

Comment: Joel summed it up pretty concisely... and Charles gave a counter-example. So I'll go with Joel's addition of "odd" to any starting value.

Comment: I am thoroughly impressed by Tomas's answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

We can produce an infinite family of counterexamples for the case where the starting value is odd.

Let $p\geq 7$ be an arbitrary prime. Then $p-1$ is even, so

$$2^{p-1}-1\equiv (-1)^{p-1} -1 \equiv 1-1 =0 \pmod 3$$

So $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{3}\in\mathbb Z$ and this number is odd, because $2^{p-1}-1$ is odd. So, take it as starting value, the Collatz sequence is:
$$\left(\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{3},2^{p-2},2^{p-3},\dots,1\right)$$
By Fermat's little theorem:
$$2^{p-1}-1\equiv 0\pmod p$$
The condition on $p$ ensures, that $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{3}>p$ holds. But $p\mid 2^{p-1}-1$ implies $p\mid\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{3}$ (because $p\neq 3$), so this number can not be prime. Hence, the sequence contains no primes (except $2$ of course).

---

You could always exclude this case. However, it seems like we could continue to produce other counter-examples using this very same "back-engineering" technique to produce a Collatz sequence with non-prime initial values, that leads to a power of $2$. This strongly suggests that a characterisation of such starting values is not easy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be better investigated when the Collatz-transformation is considered by its inverse. And usually I define the compressed Collatz-transformation as beginning at an odd integer $a$, doing one step $ a'=3a+1$ and including also all steps $a''=a'/2. a'''=a''/2,... b$ until $b$ is odd again. In short
$$ a \to b \text{ is defined as } \qquad b = {3a+1 \over 2^A } \qquad \qquad \text{ where $A$ is such that $b$ is odd} $$
The "inverse" view at this is the 2-parametric map, depending on odd $b$ and $A$
$$ a = {b \cdot 2^A -1 \over 3}\qquad \qquad \text{ where $A$ is such that numerator is divisible by $3$} $$
For instance, for $b=1$ we get for increasing $A$ the sequence $$a_{b,k} = \{ 1,5,21,85,341,...\} = { 1 \cdot 4^k-1 \over 4-1} \qquad \text{and } A = 2k$$ giving us that all $a_{1,k}$ fall down to $b=1$ by one compressed Collatz transformation, thus involving only exactly 1 odd number. So we have already a handful of examples:
$$ \begin{array} {}
 a_{1,2} \to 1 &:& 5,16,8,4,2,1  &\text { and $5$ is prime} \\ 
 a_{1,3} \to 1 &:& 21,64,32,16,8,4,2,1  &\text { and $21$ is composite} \\ 
 a_{1,4} \to 1 &:& 85,256,128,...,4,2,1  &\text { and $85$ is composite and } a_{1,2} | a_{1,4} \\ 
 a_{1,5} \to 1 &:& 341,1024,512,...,4,2,1  &\text { and $341$ is composite and } 11 \cdot 31 = a_{1,5} \\ 
 a_{1,6} \to 1 &:& 1365,4096,...,4,2,1  &\text { and $1365$ is composite and } a_{1,2} | a_{1,6} \text{ and } a_{1,3} | a_{1,6} \\ 
 a_{1,7} \to 1 &:& 5461,16348,...,4,2,1  &\text { and $5461$ is composite and } 43 \cdot 127 = a_{1,7} \\  ...
\end{array} $$ and  I think the fact of $a_{1,k}$ being composite keeps on 
for all subsequent $k$. (I checked this up to $k=200$ and possibly this can also analytically be shown.)
After that we can proceed and using all $a_{1,k}$ we can set $b_k=a_{1,k}$ and ***as far as $b_k$ is not divisible by $3$*** we can determine for increasing $A$ the sequences $a_{b_k,j} $. For instance for $b_2=5$ we get $$ a_{5,j}= \{ 3,13,53,213,...\} = { 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 4^{j-1}-1 \over 4-1} \qquad \text{and } A = 2j-1$$ and all of that numbers $a_{5,j}$ have the prime $5$ in their trajectory down to $1$: {$ 3,10,\quad 5,16,8,4,2,1$}, {$13,40,20,10,\quad 5,16,8,4,2,1$} and so on.

Of course all $a_{85,j}$,$a_{341,j}$, ... have the next odd number in their trajectory composite as far as $85,341,...$ are composite themselves - and this follows readily from the above discussed list.

The occurence of primes in the lists $a_{b,j}$ (for any valid $b$ and $j$)  is at most spurious, and the more lists are involved in that iteratively expansible system the spuriousness of primes in the *trajectories* shall be exponentially improve, so most of the trajectories in this view of the Collatz-transformation show compositeness of at least one member and a conjecture might possibly better formulated as complementary of yours : *"most trajectories contain at most one prime"* - and perhaps this can be made much sharper by deeper consideration of the above scheme.

Answer (score -2):

Disregarding 2, this will not always be the case if we simply choose a power of 2 (128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1). This is known as the Martin counterexample.

Comment: "This is known as the Martin counterexample." It is, is it?

Comment: “Will not be the case […] 4, 2, 1.” Is 2 not prime now?